# Sharepoint Designer 2007 configuration

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Every time I open SPDESIGN 2007 it runs through the configuration. It runs for about 30 seconds and then opens the program. This is nothing if not annoying. Is there any way to fix this?

OS: Windows 7 x64, SP 1; Version: Sharepoint Designer 2007, SP1

Answer (score 0):

Are you running several versions of Office side by side? If so, you may want to set a registry key that prevents the dialog.  For details see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928091?wa=wsignin1.0

The gist is:

> To bypass the auto-registration for Word 2007, follow these steps:
>   Exit Word 2007. Start Registry Editor. In Windows Vista, click Start,
>   type regedit in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.
>
> If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a
>   confirmation, type the password, or click Continue. In Windows XP,
>   click Start, click Run, type regedit in the Open box, and then click
>   OK. Locate and then click to select the following registry subkey:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options After
>   you select the subkey that is specified in step 3, point to New on the
>   Edit menu, and then click DWORD Value. Type NoReReg, and then press
>   ENTER. Right-click NoReReg, and then click Modify. In the Value data
>   box, type 1, and then click OK. On the File menu, click Exit to close
>   Registry Editor.

Comment: I'm running Office 2010. Previous to that was running Office 2003 (we skipped over 2007). I don't have the reg key that you reference, so I'm hesitant to add it. I'm running SPDesigner 2007 because the SP server to which I'm connecting is MOSS 2007.